# How can I wake my laptop from suspend only on power button?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, lenovo

My Lenovo G560 wakes up from suspend in my backpack sometimes and I hate it. I would power off the whole system, but gnome shell (which I like) starts very slowly.

Is there a way to make the system resume from suspend only by pressing the power button?

I use Ubuntu 12.04 with GNOME 3.4.2

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/711528/power-button-after-suspend-causes-reboot-instead-of-wake-up

Comment: @donquixote sad, but the question you directed me to was removed. Thank you nonetheless!