# Only wake up when pressing power button, not any other button

Tags: keyboard, suspend, power-management, 16.10

I only want to wake up my laptop when pressing the power button, not any other button (e.g. when I clean the keyboard, the laptop wakes up making cleaning impossible). How can I change this?

I noticed the question [How can I wake my laptop from suspend only on power button?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196051/how-can-i-wake-my-laptop-from-suspend-only-on-power-button) but the answer got deleted.